# Android library dependencies that also depend on each other

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I provide a set of "Service" libraries, released as AARs, each providing their own functionality. Naturally, all these libraries depend on some common functionality which is packaged as the "Core" library. Customers will use the Service libraries they need and include them as dependencies in their projects. The problem is, when someone tries to use more than one Service library, their build will fail as each of those libraries will try to build Core which results to conflicting BuildConfigs for it.

I presume the solution is to not include Core as a dependency in each of the Service libraries and instead ask the user to add it to their project's dependencies. The problem is, in order for the above to work, one needs to make sure Gradle builds Core before building the Service libraries, which i don't know how. Is it even possible with Gradle ? I'm also open to suggestion in case my current system isn't a good idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe provide instructions to exclude core from all but one library in the gradle file?  Not sure if that would do it.

Comment: @nasch Users will be fetching the AARs from our maven repo, and we also want to minimize the hassle and avoid the user from fiddling with code, so I don't think it works.